# pfSense Crash Logs

Tags: firewall, crash, pfsense

I am running pfsense 2.3.2 on a (pretty old) Watchguard Firexbox X750e. The only services running on it is a DHCP server. No major traffic filtering or encryption. Every now and then when watching Netflix I will lose my connection to the Internet, and I won't be able to access the LAN WebGui. The only way I've known to fix this is to power cycle the Watchguard.

**Are there any logs I can view by attaching to the console port? Most of the logs I find in the WebGui only start populating at boot, so I can't go back and review any error messages that may have been written when the system crashed.**

The reason I mention my specs is that I'm wondering if the hardware is too old for running pfsense today. I don't have gigabit speeds or anything on the LAN. I'm not running snort. I don't think I'd be hitting the limit for processor capability.

Pfsense reports on an average day I'm using 21% of the 471 MB of RAM and only about 30% of disk usage. CPU is a Celeron M @ 1300Mhz My average load is:  0.13,  0.11,  0.04

Comment: Try looking at the "monitoring" graphs (formerly RRD) and system resource use/traffic/loss etc. there.

Comment: The only problem with that is when this crash occurs the WebGUI goes completely down and doesn't come up again without a reboot.